# How to Cross-Compile from LLVM IR to Assembly for ARM Cortex M4?

Tags: arm, llvm, cross-compiling, llc

I'm trying to cross-compile an llvm-ir file to assembly, or better generate an object file, for an ARM Cortex M4 microprocessor using llc compiler.
Which are the parameters that I have to specify in order to do so?
I have tried with this command
`llc -mtriple=armv7m-eabi -mcpu=cortex-m4 file.ll -o file.s`
It doesn't throw any error but the assembly code generated is still for an x86 machine.

In particular, trying to compiling with random parameters, e.g.
`llc -mtriple=randomwords -mcpu=cortex-m4 file.ll -o file.s`
It goes smooth, producing an assembly code for the x86 machine. It ignores what I specify.

Comment: older llvm versions this used to work great, newer versions, not so much.  I ended up building my llvm toolchain specifically for the armv7-m target and that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, or better a work around to this problem.
Instead of using directly llc, first I've obtained the binary code through this command
`llvm-as file.ll -o file.bc`
An than I used clang to crosscompile and obtain the object file for ARM Cortex M4 using this instruction
`clang --target=arm-none-eabi -march=armv7e-m -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -nostdlib file.bc -c -o file.o`
The `-c` is used to compile only.
It is also possible to obtain the assembly code by using the following command line
`clang -S --target=arm-none-eabi -march=armv7e-m -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -nostdlib file.bc -o file.s`

Answer (score 0):

llc (not sure about prior to v9) seems to only care about the architecture.
I can cross compile and link with the following script (for a RPI running Linux):

```
#/bin/sh
llc-9 -march=arm -float-abi=hard -O3 -filetype obj $1.ll -o $1.o
~/devel/musl/musl-cross-make/output/bin/arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc -mfloat-abi=hard -static $1.o -o $1
```

llc --version will show the available architectures

Try the following for your case (or use a more specific architecture if it is in the list):

```
llc -march=arm -mcpu=cortex-m4 -filetype obj file.ll -o file.o
```